# Why can I not send an email from Hotmail using "Outlook Connect"?

Tags: windows-xp, email, microsoft-outlook, sp3, microsoft-outlook-2003

Why can I not send an email from Hotmail using "Outlook Connect"?

I can receive them.

XP Pro SP3.

Thanks.

Comment: We need a bit more information. What settings are you using? did it **ever** work? Is there anything in the event log for applications? Do you receive any errors when you try?

Comment: Thanks.
- I just installed it a few days ago. It immediately received but will not send.
- No errors.
- Event log??

Comment: As I go back to the website for this, I see that it only refers to READING your email - it says nothing about sending it. Is this the answer?

Comment: Don't think so. From http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9a2279b1-df0a-46e1-aa93-7d4870871ecf&displaylang=en , "Outlook Connector enables you to use your Live Hotmail accounts within Outlook: Read and send your Office Live Mail/Windows Live Hotmail e-mail messages."

Comment: Thyanks John T.

Comment: Can't speyll....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at last I have a solution. Thanks to all, but I was finally able to resolve this through other help.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/use-hotmail-from-microsoft-outlook/

I then got an error message which I tracked down here: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/312354

Voila, all works.